# check if command was successful in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, exit-code, errorlevel

How within a batch file to check if command

```
start "" javaw -jar %~p0/example.jar
```

was successful or produced an error?

I want to use if/else statements to echo this info out.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use

```
if errorlevel 1 echo Unsuccessful
```

in some cases. This depends on the last command returning a proper exit code. You won't be able to tell that there is anything wrong if your program returns normally even if there was an abnormal condition.

Caution with programs like Robocopy, which require a more nuanced approach, as the error level returned from that is a bitmask which contains more than just a boolean information and the actual success code is, AFAIK, 3.

Comment: This is the right answer as it is more explicit than checking `%errorlevel%` as [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743).

Comment: @TomášZato: It will trigger on any positive exit code.

Comment: @sschuberth That link is now broken, updated link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743

Comment: @sschuberth what if errorlevel is -1?

Comment: What about it @marco-sulla?

Comment: @sschuberth Well, `if errorlevel 1` does not work, since it checks only if errorlevel is greater than 1. IMHO the only safe way to check if there's an error is to check if errorlevel is not equal to zero.

Comment: Indeed, I just verified that the `errorlevel` is signed on Windows, and an `exit /b -1` does *not* result in `errorlevel` to be 255 (like it would have been the case in DOS times), but -1. Anyway, the point of this answer was to use `errorlevel` instead of `%errorlevel%`, and the comparison was just an example IMO.

Answer (score 91):

This likely doesn't work with `start`, as that starts a new window, but to answer your question:

If the command returns a error level you can check the following ways

**By Specific Error Level**

```
commandhere
if %errorlevel%==131 echo do something
```

**By If Any Error**

```
commandhere || echo what to do if error level ISN'T 0
```

**By If No Error**

```
commandhere && echo what to do if error level IS 0
```

If it does not return a error level but does give output, you can catch it in a variable and determine by the output, example (note the tokens and delims are just examples and would likely fail with any special characters)

**By Parsing Full Output**

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('somecommand') do set output=%%a
if %output%==whateveritwouldsayinerror echo error
```

Or you could just look for a single phrase in the output like the word *Error*

**By Checking For String**

```
commandhere | find "Error" || echo There was no error!
commandhere | find "Error" && echo There was an error!
```

And you could even mix together (just remember to escape `|` with `^|` if in a `for` statement)

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to check not equal?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 20):

Most commands/programs return a 0 on success and some other value, called `errorlevel`, to signal an error.

You can check for this in you batch for example by:

```
call <THE_COMMAND_HERE>
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto :next
echo "Errors encountered during execution.  Exited with status: %errorlevel%"
goto :endofscript

:next
echo "Doing the next thing"

:endofscript
echo "Script complete"
```

Answer (score 8):

Goodness I had a hard time finding the answer to this... Here it is:

```
cd thisDoesntExist
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
  echo Oh, I guess it does
  echo Huh.
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if javaw will write to the %errorlevel% variable, but it might.

`echo %errorlevel%` after you run it directly to see.

Other than that, you can pipe the output of javaw to a file, then use `find` to see what the results were. Without knowing the output of it, I can't really help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

So logically, this would test for success:

```
if not errorlevel 1 echo success
```

Well, unless there's a negative exit code, which would be unusual.  This also has the bonus of seeing what the errorlevel is.

```
if %errorlevel%==0 echo success
```