# BAT file check for at least one error after sequence of reg-commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

I have a bat-file with 10 reg commands. I need bat-file at the end of its work display a message if at least 1 error is occurred and pause.

I have read this manuals
http://ss64.com/nt/if.html
http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html
and they are completely unclear. As I see there are 2 variables ERRORLEVEL - system and local. But in many stackoverflow answers both variables are used:
[How do I make a batch file terminate upon encountering an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734598/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-terminate-upon-encountering-an-error)
[check if command was successfull in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691494/check-if-command-was-successfull-in-a-batch-file)
So if some application return some code simultaneously with bat-file I can get wrong behaviour. So I need local ERRORLEVEL. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Note of caution by @dbenham:

> It is possible for a user to set an ERRORLEVEL environment variable that overrides the intended dynamic %ERRORLEVEL% value. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx) for more information.

So unless you do strange things like manually assigning to `errorlevel`, there is only one `errorlevel` variable and it is set locally for the currently executed batch file by the last executed command in your batch file. It's called a system variable only because it's set by system, not by you, the user.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
reg do something1 || set error=, 1
reg do something2 || set error=!error!, 2
reg do something3 || set error=!error!, 3

if not "!error!"="" echo Failed tasks: !error:~2!
```

Comment: `set error=, 1` assigns `, 1` to the variable `error` and `set error=!error!, 2` sets it to the previous value plus `, 2`. At the end of execution the first two characters are stripped: `!error:~2!`. Exclamation marks are used instead of `%` because of [enableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: Um. ", 1" is a string or what? If this is string , where are quote marks? If this is not a string , what comma means?

Comment: Batch file syntax [does not require quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) for strings in `set` assignments. The comma is added for the reasons I've stated above - the first two characters are stripped in the end.

Comment: +1, Your code is fine, but your explanation is a bit misleading, given that it is possible for a user to set an ERRORLEVEL environment variable that overrides the intended dynamic `%ERRORLEVEL%` value. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx for more information. This is a tricky topic.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've included your note in the answer if you don't mind.