# Windows, how to handle return value from netstat? ( batch / .bat )

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is my code :

```
@echo off
netstat -a -n | find /c "127.0.0.1:80"
pause
```

It return 1 Value in my CMD. i want to make IF Condition, for example, if The return value is 1 do this, if 0 do this. can you help me guys?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691494/check-if-command-was-successfull-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably just use this construct:

```bat
NetStat -na | Find "127.0.0.1:80" >Nul && (
    Echo Found
) || (
    Echo Not found
)
```

Change `Echo Found` to the command(s) you need for one or more matches and `Echo Not found` to the command(s) you need for no connection matches a little like this:

*Depending upon your specific requirements you could possibly replace `-na` with `-np TCP`*

*BTW your script is returning the value from `find` not from `netstat`.*

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the command in a for /f parsing the output.

```
@echo off
For /f %%A in ('netstat -a -n ^| find /c "127.0.0.1:80"') Do Set Count=%%A
If %Count% equ 0 (
  echo Count = 0 do this
) Else (
  echo Count not 0 do that
)
pause
```