# Batch Detecting Program Not Responding

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script that detects if an .exe is not responding, and if it isn't, it will run a piece of code that kills it and then does some other things as well. I know how I can kill the process and restart it if it is not responding in one line, but I am not sure how I can do more than just restart it by converting this into an if statement, or calling a goto.

```
taskkill /im "exeName.exe" /fi "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" /f >nul && start "" "pathToExe"
```

I have come across other Stack Overflow posts that are similar to this, however they only check the error level of the process and do not check if the program is not responding and how to perform code after that.

How would I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if command was successful in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691494/check-if-command-was-successful-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: @KenY-N That does not check if the task is not responding. That only checks if there are other errors such as if it is not currently running.

Comment: Is the problem that you want something like "if not responding then do something other than kill the process"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am interpreting your question correctly and you want to test without killing a task, how about this:

```
tasklist /fi "status eq not responding" /nh | find "exeName.exe" >NUL
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo Oops, we've hung...
)
```

[`tasklist`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist) takes the same `/fi status` options as `taskkill`, even though the documentation states only `RUNNING` is allowed - `taskkill /?` on Windows 8 at least shows the full options. We then use `find` to check that the executable is in the list of not responding tasks.

BTW, if you want to use [`PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6) instead:

```
$foo = get-process exeName
if (!$foo.Responding) {
    echo "Oops, we've hung..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done more easily:

```
taskkill /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" /IM "yourexe.exe" /F | findstr /c:"SUCCESS" >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (echo Successfully detected and terminated "yourexe.exe" which didn't respond) else (echo Ooops! We didn't find or could not terminate process "yourexe.exe")
```

---

If you want to just **detect** if process is not responding, then use `tasklist`:

```
tasklist /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" | findstr /c:"yourexe.exe">nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (echo We have detected that process with image name "yourexe.exe" is not responding.) else (echo We didn't found process with image name "yourexe.exe" because it doesn't exist.)
```

---

In both cases we use `findstr` command because even if process not found/terminated `taskkill`/`tasklist` will return `errorlevel` `0`.