# Bat file to kill IE if not responding

Tags: batch-file

I need some help to close IE if the IE window title becomes not responding.

This gives me an error.

```
@echo off
Title Start and Kill Internet Explorer
Mode con cols=75 lines=5 & color 0B
echo(
echo   Launching Internet Explorer ...
Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.google.com"
:: Sleep for 20 seconds
Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak>NUL
echo(
echo  Killing Internet Explorer If the Status is Not Responding ...
::echo            Hit any Key to kill all instances of Internet Explorer
Pause>nul
Cls & Color 0C
echo(

::Taskkill /IM "iexplore.exe" /F
Taskkill /F "iexplore.exe"  /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq *Not Responding*"​ /FI 

pause
```

Comment: How did you get that code to make Internet Explorer unresponsive? What is the error?

Comment: Because the leading asterisk after `eq` is not allowed in `taskkill` and you will get `ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized`

Comment: Possible Duplicate Of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938743/batch-detecting-program-not-responding)